# preg_replace() help to convert {$variable} to php echo variable statement

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am working on small template class. I need help in converting {$variable} written in template file to be converted to

Like :

```
<html>
   <body>
      <p> Hey Welcome {$username} </p> 
   </body>
</html>
```

to  be converted to

```
    <html>
   <body>
      <p> Hey Welcome <?php echo $username ?> </p> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Just like variable username. there can be any variable with any length. I just want to convert it to php echo statment.

I think it is possible with preg_replace() but don't know how.

Comment: You can read how here:http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Why don't you try simple: $html_template = str_replace('{$username}', $username, $html_template);

Comment: Why `preg_replace()` and not `str_replace()`? Why replace it with PHP code instead of the real value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

```
$string = 'Hello {$username}, how are you?';
$new_string = preg_replace('/\{(\$[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)\}/', '<?php echo \\1; ?>', $string);
echo $new_string;
```

Which gives this:

```
Hello <?php echo $username; ?>, how are you?
```

I borrowed that expression from the php manual..

> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid
>   variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any
>   number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression,
>   it would be expressed thus: '**[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]***'

So in theory it should match any valid variable.

Comment: Will you tell me any tutorial for regular expression

Comment: @Poush One good resource that springs to mind is [regular-expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/\{\$username\}/', '<?php echo $username; ?>', $text);
```

or in general:

```
preg_replace('/\{\$([^\}]+)\}/', '<?php echo $$1; ?>', $text);
```

Comment: Thank you! Will you tell me any tutorial for regular expression ?

Answer (score 0):

For example:
you have app folder structure:

- app/view/index.template
- app/controller/index.php
- app/index.php

Where "app" folder is webroot

So, file "app/view/index.template" contains:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <p> Hey Welcome {$username} </p> 
   </body>
</html>
```

And "app/controller/index.php" contains next:

```
<?php
    $username = 'My Hero';
    $content = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '../view/index.template');
    if ($content) {
        echo str_replace('{$username}', $username, $content);
    } else { echo 'Sorry, file not found...';}
```

And "app/index.php" contains next:

```
<?php
    include __DIR__ . '/controller/index.php';
```

Something like that...

Comment: Your idea in nice but my script has not limited variable. I have to write str_replace() for each statement which is not even set(known) when making controller. Controller will get list of variables by another script/page during executing.

Comment: It is possible to use it in that way: 

str_replace(array('tmp1', 'tmp2', ... 'tmp_n'), array($var1, $var2, ... $var_n), $content);

Comment: Note, preg functions eats huge count resources, where it possible we aren't need use them.

Comment: And you can organize you template handler function with loop like:
$vars = array('tmp_1'=>$var1, 'tmp_2'=>$var2, ... 'tmp_n'=>$var_n);
echo render($content, $vars);

function render($content, $vars) {
foreach ($vars as $tmp => $var)
{
 str_replace("{$$tmp}", $var, $content);
}
return $content;
}